# Show and hide elements for different exporters

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I show and hide specific elements in a Jasper Reports template (JRXML)
according the export type,  for example

```
<reportElement x="0" y="70" width="342" height="90">
    <printWhenExpression>
        <![CDATA[$V{IS_PDF}]]>
    </printWhenExpression>
</reportElement>

<reportElement x="0" y="70" width="342" height="90">
    <printWhenExpression>
        <![CDATA[$V{IS_XSL}]]>
    </printWhenExpression>
</reportElement>
```

I don't want to pass the IS_PDF, or IS_XSL within the report parameters, I am asking if there is a way within the template it's self to indicate the export type

Comment: You can also use *JasperReports API* or some wrapper (*DynamicJasper* or *DynamicReports*) on it

Comment: yes, it's duplicate but the other one has a not clear title,  I went threw it at first, but even didn't read 
so it will be great if the other question gets a more abstract title,  e.g.  
show hide report elements according the export type 

however, thanks a lot this solved my problem

Comment: You are welcome :)